# Записать числа в текстовый файл C#

Tags: c#

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.
Есть такое задание:
Создать файл, компоненты которого случайные целые числа, большие единицы. Найти наименьшее число. Создать новый файл, содержащий четыре степени такого числа.
Создаю файл с рандомными числами все ок, а дальше тупик. Как найти минимальное число и работать с ним?

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileStream numbers = new FileStream("d:\\numbersRandom.txt",
            FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(numbers);
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            write.Write(rand.Next(1, 50) + ",");
        }
        write.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Что такое "компоненты файла"?

Comment: Это в задании так написано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте файл

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
```

Разбейте прочитанное на подстроки

```
string[] tokens = text.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

И ищите минимальное

```
int min = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
{
    int number = int.Parse(tokens[i]);
    if (i == 0 || number < min)
        min = number;
}
Console.WriteLine("min = " + min);
```

Как записать то что нужно дальше в файл, вы уже умеете.